# How to get background location of modal window from previous page, like Unsplash did?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

The **background page** of modal window in Unsplash is really unique.

Emulation:

1. **click** on photo from feed
2. then **click** to another photo on modal page to watch effect
3. refresh page
4. click to **go back** on browser
5. notice the **route** of background location on modal window

So my question is how to create this background location properly?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, my personal point of view is that when you go back, Unsplash page re-triggers the modal window you open before. Unspalsh is written in React so, for example, code could be like that:

```
function Page() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({...});
  useEffect(() => {
      // get data from cache
      if (data) {
        // (re)open dialog with photo
      }
  }, [state]); // state in deps so useEffect will be re-triggered each time you enter in Page
}
```

I don't want to be reductive but this could be a start point.